# Reloading Soudcloud html5 widget after json

Tags: jquery, json, soundcloud

Im attempting to load multiple html5 widgets from soundcloud after a json call. I make the json call then append stuff to my main div, but the widgets dont load properly.  I suspect this to do with the timing of function calls.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
var url='https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=client_id';
$.getJSON(url, function(tracks){
    $.each(tracks, function(key,value){
        $('#container').append('<a href="' + value.permalink_url +  '" class="sc-player">MY NEW DUB TRAXXXXX</a>');
    });
});
});
</script>

<div id="container">
<a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic" class="sc-player"> My new dub track</a></div>
```

The a tag in the div loads properly, but not the stuff added by jquery.  How can I reload/refresh/re-init the JS to transform my links?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use the [oembed](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#oembed) endpoint. You pass it the permalink of the track you want and it responds with the correct widget embed code which you can put straight into the document.